# Expdp from Oracle RAC environment

Tags: oracle

On running following command on one of the RAC Instance

```
expdp system/password@orcl DIRECTORY=Test DUMPFILE=user1.dmp owner=user1 LOGFILE=log1.log
```

I am facing following error:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

I have created the 'Test' directory using following SQL command on the same RAC instance:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY Test AS '/usr/apps/datafiles';
```

Can you please help me in exporting DB successfully?

Comment: Does the `/usr/apps/datafiles` directory already exist, and is it writable by the Oracle account?

Comment: yes, datafile was successfully created and has write permission as well.

Comment: `datafile` or `datafiles` - assume that's just a typo in the comment? Are there any files in the directory; particularly does the log file already exist, owned by someone else or read-only?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is `ORA-29283`:

```
> oerr ora 29283
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

So either the `/usr/apps/datafiles` directory doesn't exist, or it is not writable by the Oracle process owner (e.g. the `oracle` account); or possibly (but less likely) the log file you specified already exists and can't be overwritten.

Since you've said it exists, look at the full permissions of the directory (e.g. `ls -ld /usr/apps/datafiles`, check the owner and group of the Oracle process owner (e.g. `id -a`) to compare the permissions on that directory and its parent. If that all looks OK, while logged in as the Oracle process owner check if you can create a file under the directory e.g.:

```
touch /usr/apps/datafiles/test_file
ls -l /usr/apps/datafiles/test_file
rm -f /usr/apps/datafiles/test_file
```

---

If all of that works, and I guess it probably does from your comment, then since you're using RAC you might need to refer to support note 1305166.1.

First thing to try is doing the `expdp` without the `@orcl`, as it seems (a) there are issues when the listener and database are running under different accounts (e.g. `grid` and `oracle`, and the `grid` user can't access the OS directory - repeat the `touch` test as that user to see if that's the case); or (b) if the alias is load-balanced and it's ending up running on a different node which doesn't have the directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the logfile to the any other default directory like DATA_PUMP_DIR, so that even it executes on any other node, as the default directory will be available on all nodes.

```
logfile=DATA_PUMP_DIR:impdp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The users might not have permission to use the directory.
You need to login as sysdba and provide the necessary permissions

grant read, write on directory to PUBLIC;

Then try the export using data pump, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting ORA-39002; ORA-39070 and ORA-39087 when running expdp.

For example:

```
$ expdp dbschema/dbpassw DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=Test1.dmp logfile=Test1.log SCHEMAS=dbschema

Export: Release xx.x.x.x.x – xxbit Production on Tuesday, xx xxxxxxxx, xxxx xx:xx:xx

Copyright (c) 2003, 2007, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release xx.x.x.x.x – xxbit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name DATA_PUMP_DIR is invalid
```

Solution:

```
grant read, write on directory DATA_PUMP_DIR to system, dbschema;
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre doing this exercise for an exercise in:
Oracle Database 11gR2 Jumpstart Guide
Chapter 9 page 87
(I'm on Windows 10)
..after doing

> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY exp_dir AS 'c:\oraclexe\exp_dumps';
>   --i also saw a link that said to add a \ to the end of this path 
>   --so 'c:\oraclexe\exp_dumps\'
>   --I'm not sure if that is also what fixed my problem so I'm including this

and

> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY exp_dir TO hr;

--i just used system here also

next
just go to that parent directory and manually create the 'exp_dumps' directory manually

then it worked for me