# Oracle export using expdp gives ORA-29283: invalid file operation error

Tags: oracle, export, expdp, oracle-dump

I want to export my database using expdp and I am running the below command for export:

```
expdp SYSTEM/SYSTTEM PARFILE=export_dump.par
```

The export_dump.par file contains the below information:

```
DIRECTORY=datapump
DUMPFILE=I.dmp
LOGFILE=I.log
SCHEMAS=RD,RC
CONTENT=ALL
```

I have all the permission for the directory datapump.But still, when I try to run the export command I am getting an error as :

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Comment: Does the directory the `datapump` is defined for exist (on the database server, not your client machine, if they are different)? Can the Oracle O/S user read and write to that operating system directory?

Comment: yes oracle o/s user are able read and write to that operating system datapump directory because when i try to export the other database from the same commany using different ip and sid then its export the database

Comment: If you're connecting to a different IP then it's a different database server; the directory has to exist on 172.17.1.2 and be read/writable by Oracle on 172.17.1.2.

Comment: yes the directory do exist in database server. Because previously i tried directly on server to run the export command

Comment: Have you created this directory in the database, i.e. can you see it in dba_directories/user_directories?

Comment: yes when i did select * from dba_directories it shows me                           SYS DATAPUMP /home/ratormonitor/datapump but how to check for user_directories ?

Comment: dba_directories view contains everything that user_directories does. So this is not your case. Are you sure that the user, who started the database, has enough permissions to write to /home/ratormonitor/datapump ?

Comment: when i tried to edit any file its says permission denied,so it might be permission issue. I can see datapump directory has permission drwx- and the ratormonitor directory has permission drwsrwsrwx and the export_dump.par file has permission -rwxrwxrw-

Comment: Who are the owners of all these directories? Why do you think drwx- is enough? Is it drwx- --- --- ? Who started the database? How do they relate to your user. We need this information to understand the situation. Anyway, it is probably a permission issue.  Can you show us the output of `find /home/ratormonitor/datapump -type d -ls`, `id`, `ps -ef | grep smon`, `select * from dba_directories where directory_name = 'datapump'`?

Comment: select * from dba_directories where directory_name = 'datapump' does not return anythin because directory name is in caps, and find /home/ratormonitor/datapump -type d -ls, id, ps -ef | grep smon gives an error as find: unknown predicate `-ls,'

Comment: I wanted to see the permissions and owner:owner_group of /home/ratormonitor/datapump, /home/ratormonitor and /home, what is your user and group: `id` and who started the database `ps -ef | grep smon`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `system` has permission on mentioned directory. If not then give permission:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY datapump TO SYSTEM;
```

If its not fixed then please refer to below links

> https://community.oracle.com/thread/2253168?tstart=0
>
> http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_39002_ora_39070_ora_29283.htm

Comment: well, does DB user SYSTEM has permission on datapump?

Comment: yes it has all the permission because in my previous it was working fine and i did not change the permission. datapump directory has permission drwx- and the ratormonitor directory has permission drwsrwsrwx and the export_dump.par file has permission -rwxrwxrw-

Comment: Please go through the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878631/expdp-from-oracle-rac-environment

Answer (score 0):

try to make the folder path inside your current desktop folder path , **this 100% works for oracle 12c and windows 10**.